# How to create dynamic params from Noticed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, notifications, rubygems

I am using Noticed gem for my notifications and I am trying to get the users for the notifications related to the post and conversation in a cleaner way. The notification stores the post as an object inside params. I'm running into a lot of repeating code because I have Groups with conversations in it and Discussions with posts in it. So I have a "post_notification" and a "conversation_notification". So when a user checks his notifications this is what's working for me right now.

```
  - if notification.params[:conversation]
    - if avatar_url_for(notification.to_notification.params[:conversation].user).present?
      = image_tag avatar_url_for(notification.to_notification.params[:conversation].user, size: 35), class: "rounded-circle"
    - else
      = image_tag "no-photo-avatar.png", class: "rounded-circle"
  - if notification.params[:post]
    - if avatar_url_for(notification.to_notification.params[:post].user).present?
      = image_tag avatar_url_for(notification.to_notification.params[:post].user, size: 35), class: "rounded-circle"
    - else
      = image_tag "no-photo-avatar.png", class: "rounded-circle"
```

```
  - noticed_notification = notification.to_notification
  = link_to noticed_notification.message, noticed_notification.url
  &nbsp;by:
  - if notification.params[:conversation]
    = notification.params[:conversation].user.full_name
  - if notification.params[:post]
    = notification.params[:post].user.full_name
```

How can I make this better not repeating or dynamic? I wanted to create a method where it's cleaner and not repeating so I can use it on the navbar notification dropdown and notification page